# Visual Studio: Shrinking text and size of secondary windows

Tags: visual-studio

i have a 55inch 1080p tv, and working split screen is still difficult because the font and overall size of the solution explorer, output window, and top menu are too large. 3pt font would be fine, but it's defaulted at 12pt.

picture below for reference. on a 55inch screen the font in solution explore is massive, can i make it smaller so i can shrink the window and still see the filenames?

[image]

Comment: You could - if you had a higher-DPI display (like a 4K display, that way you could just run Windows at a lower DPI setting) but at 96dpi you're SOL; and the font-size of the rest of VS' UI is based on your system default font-size. You can fiddle with it, but I don't recommend it (as it tends to break everything else). You _really_ should get a proper monitor instead of using a TV as a monitor. TVs generally make for poor computer displays because (warning: subjective anecdote ahead) they have harsher backlights, poor input lag, and don't handle low-contrast in dark colors well. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! "the rest of VS' UI is based on your system default font-size" - i had my font-size at 300% dropped that to 100% and it's a major difference.